How to add vertices to the surface of the circle so I can sculpt on it?
First image shows the doorknob model in Blender, and second shows the effect I want to achieve.




For something like that you want to select these edges and use a bevel with Ctrl+B.
The scroll wheel on the mouse controls how many cuts you can add, which will make the curve smoother. You can also play with the parameters on the pop up window

You can also do this in a non destructive way with a Bevel modifier. You can limit what edges get affected and how much with the Mean Bevel Wight slider (Select the edges you want and make that 100% or whatever you want)
Then set the modifier's 'Limit Method' to Weight
This method results in less geometry.
You also probably want the flat face to be divided into equal quads instead of having just 2 edges connecting them

